# Hebrew RTL (right to left) text on Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, right-to-left

I have to get a input TextField to work reversed to support hebrew text, which is a "right to left" language. I need something as google's translator on hebraic mode (go to translate.google.com and select hebraic as the input language)

I'm using Flash CS5 and AS3, exporting for Adobe AIR 2.0.

Is there some ready solution? I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going straight to the properties panel of a text field and changing it to TLF instead of classic. Then go to Edit > Preferences > Text and mark the "Shot right to left text options", then hit OK. Go back to the properties panel of the text field and look for the "right to left" option

Hope it helps, that is the best solution I could find.

Cheers!

Comment: This answer gets older, because latest version of flash do not have such option.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player 10 supports right-to-left using the new classes in the `flashx.textLayout` package and subpackages.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/package-detail.html

I searched and couldn't find any example, either in the help or elsewhere.